# JBoss with hibernate using inifinispan as the second level cache provider

Tags: hibernate, jboss, infinispan

I am using JBoss 6.1 and JPA/Hibernate (3.6) as the second level cache with Infinispan (4.2) being the cache provider

My question would be : is there a difference between cache strategy READ-WRITE and cache strategy TRANSACTIONAL ? I am asking this because as far as i understood Infinispan falls to TRANSACTIONAL cache strategy even when READ-WRITE is being specified.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with this extremely old implementation (Infinispan 4.2 was released more than 5 years ago, last ORM 3.6 release is 4+ years), but in ORM 4.x there was no difference.

Note that 2LC suffered many concurrency issues fixed in 5.0.x (fixes were not backported to 4.x as API changes were needed), so I would strongly suggest to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take in consideration migrating. Tell me one thing though : are this concurrency issues documented somewhere ?

Comment: No, but generally speaking, the result is that an entity is not invalidated properly and you read stale value until the entity is updated again.